# Interactive Python GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, pygtk, interactive, spawn

Python have been really bumpy for me, because the last time I created a GUI client, the client seems to hang when spawning a process, calling a shell script, and calling outside application.

This have been my major problem with Python since then, and now I'm in a new project, can someone give me pointers, and a word of advice in order for my GUI python application to still be interactive when spawning another process?

Comment: It's worth mentioning that keeping an interactive GUI during computation is something that needs a solution in every programing language and isn't Python specific.  Generally you're going to need to look into some sort of parallel programming to prevent the GUI thread from being blocked.  (True for any language.)

Answer (score 4):

Simplest (not necessarily "best" in an abstract sense): spawn the subprocess in a separate thread, communicating results back to the main thread via a Queue.Queue instance -- the main thread must periodically check that queue to see if the results have arrived yet, but periodic polling isn't hard to arrange in any event loop.

Answer (score 2):

Your main GUI thread will freeze if you spawn off a process and wait for it to completely. Often, you can simply use subprocess and poll it now and then for completion rather than `wait`ing for it to finish. This will keep your GUI from freezing.